# Cancel a pod with error ImageBackoff

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to deploy a kubernetes pod and I get a error ImagePullBackOff

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mrp-7c46596899-cvjnf   1/1     Running            0          33d
mrp-7c46596899-mv5s5   1/1     Running            0          33d
mrp-8f5796f45-xnggf    0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          9m8s
```

Is there a way that I can cancel this deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to delete this deployment as the pod is not able to pull specified image.

Try these steps:

1. `kubectl get deployment` (this will list all deployments in the default namespace).
2. `kubectl delete deployment mrp` (mrp or the deployment name you created).